# Calculating primes with long (Java)

Tags: java, string, boolean, primes, long-integer

I want to write a little program which is able to find the first 10 digit long prime number out of the euler number.

The number on the 99th place is the number I am searching for, but the isPrim() method does not respond correctly. Do you see what went wrong?

My Code

```
public class Main {

    public static final String e = "27182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303535475945713821785251664274274663919320030599218174135966";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(e);
        for (int i = 0; i < e.length() - 10; i++) {

            String str = e.substring(i, i + 10);

            long num = Long.parseLong(str);

            boolean isPrim = isPrim(num);

            if (isPrim == true) {
                System.out.println("First prime: " + num);
                break;
            }

            System.out.println(i + " " + str + " " + isPrim);

        }

    }

    public static boolean isPrim(long number) {
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int j = 3; j * j < number; j+=2) {
            if (number % j == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: As Mikhail said, you need to check for leading zeros.  You could also check the last (units) digit of the ten.  Any ten digit number that ends in 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, or 8 cannot be prime as it will have 2 or 5 as a factor.  That will save you doing a full prime test for those numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Should be `j * j <= number`, otherwise you will treat squares of primes as primes.  I.e. your method says that `9` is prime, because there are no dividers less than `sqrt(9)`.

Also, your code will probably find prime that is shorter than 10 digits, because it checks all 10-digits substrings of E, including those with leading zeros, such as `0452353602`.

Also, you need to change type of `j` to `long` to avoid overflow.

Comment: I made the change you suggested, but the function still returns the wrong value

Comment: Does it return valid prime that is shorter than 10 digits?

Comment: There are numbers shorter than 10 digits because of leading zeros. They are returned not to be a prime. Here is a part of the output of my program:111 2003059921 false
112 0030599218 false
113 0305992181 false
114 3059921817 false
115 0599218174 false

Comment: I changed the datatype from int to long and the program finally worked the way I wanted. Thank you very much, Mikhail!

Comment: If the program works then you should accept the answer.